# How to show auto select next value if two values are same in php?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

```
<select name="yos_filter" id="yos_filter" class='form-control'>
    <option value="">Year/Semester</option>
    <?php 
        if ($classesRow) 
        {
            $looping = (int)$classesRow->duration;
            if ($classesRow->mode==1) 
            {
                for ($i=1; $i <=$looping; $i++) 
                {
                    if ($this->session->userdata('yos_filter')==CallYears($i)) 
                    {
                        $select =  "Selected";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $select =  "";
                    }
                    echo "<option ".$select." value=".CallYears($i).">".str_replace('_', ' ', CallYears($i))."</option>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for ($i=1; $i <=(2*$looping); $i++) 
                {
                    if ($this->session->userdata('yos_filter')==CallSemester($i)) 
                    {
                        $select =  "Selected";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $select =  "";
                    }
                    echo "<option ".$select." value=".CallSemester($i).">".str_replace('_', ' ', CallSemester($i))."</option>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

[image]

In this code I want to create auto select next value in drop down if `semester` have `1st_semester` then dropdown must be `2nd_semester` similarly if `semester` have `2nd_semester` then dropdown must be `3rd_semester` but here I have same value inside the drop down as I show in the above image. So, how can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: if dropdown have 2nd_semester so you want 3rd_semester to be selected? or also first add 3rd_semester dynamically and then seleted?

Comment: yes @YasinPatel

Comment: First one or second?

Comment: first one @YasinPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one variable `$next=0` above the loop. and when you find semester value store next value in that variable.

```
for ($i=1; $i <=(2*$looping); $i++)
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('yos_filter')==CallSemester($i))
    {
        $next =  $i+1;
    }
    $select = ($next == $i)?"selected":"";

    echo "<option ".$select." value=".CallSemester($i).">".str_replace('_', ' ', CallSemester($i))."</option>";
}
```

Do the same thing for both loop